# How to get the full URL requested in SvelteKit, on the server side?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I was trying to access the full URL to prepare the page head in sveltekit,

I tried `window.location.origin` but then SvelteKit has a 500 error with `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

```html
<svelte:head>
  <!-- Set Hreflang for SEO https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/seo/hreflang/ -->
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="{window.location.origin}" />
</svelte:head>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, you'll need to use `url.href`.

For example, in +page.server.ts:

```
export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ url }) => {
    const href = url.href;
    ...
}
```